# Does same package mean in same file?

Tags: scala

I am confused with same package and in same file.
For example:

In file Top1.scala:

```
package example

class A{ ... some stuff here ...}
```

Another file Top2.scala:

```
package example

class B{ ... some stuff here ...}
```

As above condition, can I claim class A and class B in same file due to being in same package?

Comment: Nope they are different files but in same package

Comment: Your question is unclear. You have two files and are asking if you have one file? I don't get it.

Comment: My consider condition is: I have two file and these two file are with same package

Comment: What difference would it make if you could "claim class A and class B [were] in [the] same file"? I feel there is a question behind your question here.

Answer (score 1):

No, they are different files in the same package